# How to Get QueryString in Node/Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters, query-string

How can I send/get the querystring from one page to another?

I am using: node version v0.12.3000 express 3.20.3

I am trying this way:

### page1.js

```
function p1(req, res){
    res.render('page1');
};

exports.p1= p1;

exports.post_enviar = function(req, res){
    var param1 = req.body.param1;
    res.render('page2', { param1 });
}
```

### page2.js

```
function p2(req, res){
    res.render('page2');
};

exports.p2= p2;

exports.get_enviar = function(req, res){
    var param1 = req.params.param1;
    console.log("param1: "+param1);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: To transmit data from one Express handler to another, you'd need to have another request sent, requiring an HTTP client. In the case of browsers as the client, you could use a `<form>`, rendering `param1` as the `value` of an `<input>` within it.

Comment: It is really not clear what you're trying to do.  Please describe your actual original problem (not your attempted solution) so we can understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try `var qsString = require('qs').stringify(req.query)`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't do that.

Long(er) answer: what you're trying to do involves either queuing a message in one route handler that would be consumed by another route, or otherwise simply sharing state between them.

The `post_enviar` export is stateless.  It doesn't reference any data outside itself.

To demonstrate: (warning, don't do this)... If you had two modules for route controllers like this:

```
// route1controller.js
var lastQuery = {};
module.exports.route1controller = function (req, res, next) {
  lastQuery = req.params;
  res.render(...);
}
module.exports.lastQuery = lastQuery;
```

and

```
// route2controller
var lastQuery = require('./path/to/route1controller').lastQuery;
module.exports.route2controller = function (req, res, next) {
   res.send(lastQuery);
}
```

Then the page rendered by route2controller will get the object (or array) of parameters that was last sent in a request to the route1controller.  This is just a crude way of sharing state between the two controllers, and you really don't want to do this.  Consider a more manageable solution, like logging (writing to a flat file, or database) requests to a given route, and then parsing them in a human readable way on another page.

If you're looking to get real-time information on one page about requests to another page, you'll need to look into more sophisticated solutions like websockets, or a polling for current data.